# Including a JPanel in multiple JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have had a reasonable amount of experience in Java SWING development and trying to simplify updates to the program. I have a basic menu (group of JButtons) which I would like at the top of every window (JFrame) displayed, instead of trying to maintain these buttons on each individual Frame I was wondering if it was possible to create one JPanel and "import" it into multiple JFrames, similar to how you can "include" in php (Bad example but best I can think of)

*Added after suggestion from first response*

I currently have a JPanel on my frame titled topPanel and for the initiation of this I have:
`topMenuPane = new menuPanel();`
where menuPanel is a class extending JPanel however the buttons and values in the menuPanel class are not displaying in the JFrame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Personnally, I would rather try to get rid of the multiple JFrame and get everything into a single one (possibly using tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could...

Extend `JFrame` and create a base frame all you applications must use.

**For** - Easy to maintain; centralized implementation; other developers don't need to remember to do the "setup"

**Against** - Tightly coupled to an implementation, may not be easy to extend for other developers (that might need to use the API).

---

Use a "WindowFactory" that generated the `JFrame` that all you applications use to generate there base frames.

**For** - Easy to maintain; centralized implementation; other developers don't need to remember to do the "setup"

**Against** - There is still the possibility that other developers may "choose" to not use it

Comment: Here's some more on [factory methods](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a subclass of JPanel which creates the JButtons. You can then create instances of this subclass to add to any JFrame (or any other container) you wish.